# ¿Cómo obtener el código de área de un país desde su número?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer un código para que dependiendo el número, yo obtenga de qué país es ese número. Por ejemplo:
numero = "576019181316" tendría que devolverme: **57** (que es el código del área de ese país)
*"Este número tiene 12 dígitos"*

---

Luego por ejemplo:
numero2 = "593987654321" tendría que devolver: **593** (que es el código del área de ese país)
*"Este número tiene 12 dígitos"*

---

Luego por ejemplo:
numero3 = "4930609859535" tendría que devolver: **49** (que es el código del área de ese país)
*"Este número tiene 14 dígitos"*

Y esto varía por cada país, porque hay países que incluso tienen 4 dígitos en su [código de área](https://www.genteparaviajar.com/prefijostelefonicosinternacionales.html)

---

Yo ya no sé qué más hacer... cualquier ayuda les estaré agradecido. En el lenguaje de programación que más cómodo para ustedes, más importante para mí es encontrar solución, pero de poder en C# o Java estaría espectacular!

Adjunto lo que he intentado hasta ahora (En c#)

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        /*string celular;
        celular = "123456789"; 
        
        String[] datos = new String[3];
        datos[0] = celular.Substring(0, 3);
        datos[1] = celular.Substring(3, 6);
        datos[2] = celular.Substring(6, 9);
        //datos[3] = celular.Substring(9, 11);
        String resultado = datos[0] + " " + datos[1] + " " + datos[2];*/
        
        String numero="123456789";
        
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello World"+numero.Length);
        
        String[] datos =new String[3];
        //datos[0]=numero.Substring(0, 3) == null ? "000" : numero.Substring(0, 3);
        //datos[1]=numero.Substring(3, 7) == null ? "000" : numero.Substring(3, 6);
        //datos[2]=numero.Substring(6, 9) == null ? "000" : numero.Substring(6, 9);
        
        datos[0]=numero.Substring(0, 3);
        datos[1]=numero.Substring(3, 3);
        datos[2]=numero.Substring(5, 4); //de la posicion 5, deme 4 numeros

        String resultado=datos[0]+" "+datos[1]+" "+datos[2];


        Console.WriteLine("Hello World"+resultado);
        
        //string codTelfPais = celular.Substring(0, celular.IndexOf(" ")).Replace("+", string.Empty);
        //Console.WriteLine("Hello World2  "+codTelfPais);
        
        string num1 = "‪4930609859535‬"; //14
        string num2 = "‪593963750500‬"; //12
        string num3 = "576019181316"; //12
        string num4 = "551146733487"; //12
        String num5 = "8004610335"; //10
        
        
        //ideas...
        /*
        Si el tercer digito no es cero, extraiga 3...
                problem: si hay paises que tienen 3er digito 0
                problem: que pasa si el tercer digito no es cero, pero necesito escoger solo los 2 primeros?
                
        Necesito encontrar una forma de... que el numero me venga segmentado a su correspondiente dependiendo su pais.
        
        Como le hago para en coja en algunos casos 3 y en algunos casos 2????
        
        */

        
        Console.WriteLine("Alemania: "+num1.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Ecuador"+num2.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Colombia"+num3.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Beazil"+num4.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Otro país que no recuerdo"+num5.Length);
        
        String[] datos2 = new String[4];
        datos2[0] = num2.Substring(0, 4); //desde la posicion 0, extraiga 3 digitos.
        datos2[1] = num2.Substring(3, 2);
        datos2[2] = num2.Substring(5, 5);
        datos2[3] = num2.Substring(10, 4);
        String resultado2 = datos2[0] + "-" + datos2[1] + "-" + datos2[2];

        //4930609859535
        Console.WriteLine("Hello ?? "+resultado2);

    }
    
    
    //Con una función?
        public static string FiltrarCodigoPais(string celular)
        {
            if (celular.Length == 15)
            {
                String[] datos = new String[4];
                datos[0] = celular.Substring(0, 3); //desde la posicion 0, extraiga 3 digitos.
                datos[1] = celular.Substring(3,2);
                datos[2] = celular.Substring(5, 5);
                datos[3] = celular.Substring(10, 4);
                String resultado = datos[0] + " " + datos[1] + " " + datos[2]+" " + datos[3];
                return resultado;

            }else if(celular.Length == 14)
            {
                String[] datos = new String[3];
                datos[0] = celular.Substring(0, 2); //desde la posicion 0, extraiga 3 digitos.
                datos[1] = celular.Substring(3, 3);
                datos[2] = celular.Substring(5, 4);
                String resultado = datos[0] + " " + datos[1] + " " + datos[2];
                return resultado;

            }else if(celular.Length == 12)
            {
                String[] datos = new String[4];
                datos[0] = celular.Substring(0, 2); //desde la posicion 0, extraiga 3 digitos.
                datos[1] = celular.Substring(2, 3);
                datos[2] = celular.Substring(4, 3);
                datos[3] = celular.Substring(7, 4);
                String resultado = datos[0] + " " + datos[1] + " " + datos[2]+" " + datos[3];
                return resultado;
            }

            return "000";

        }
    
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero ten en cuenta que las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas. Si tu link se cae, la pregunta se volverá inutil para futuros lectores. Te recomiendo editar la pregunta y agregarlo allí, formateado usando las {} arriba del editor de texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, con su ayuda logré codificar la solución que necesitaba:

```
public static string FiltrarCodigoPais(string celular)
    {
        
        string[] codPaises = {"593","55","57","233"};
        List<string> list = new List<string>(codPaises.ToList());
        string codPais = null;


        if (codPaises.Lenght  > 0)//246 Paises
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < codPaises.Lenght; i++)
            {
                list.Add(codPaises[i].ToString());
                codPaises = list.ToArray();
                //codPaises.Append(dt.Rows[i]["phone_code"].ToString());
                if (celular.IndexOf(codPaises[i]) == 0) //Si en la posicion 0 halla el código del país actul, lo econtonramos!
                {
                    codPais = codPaises[i];
                    //Console.Write("Se ha hallado que el código del país es " + codPaises[i] + "\n");
                }
            }
        }

        return codPais;


    }
```

Espero que a alguno le ayude esta solución a futuro también :)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

Puedes ocupar la librería [libphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber), la cual tiene versiones para muchos lenguajes, incluidos Javascript, Java, C# y Python.

Este es un ejemplo con el [paquete nuget](https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp) en C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] telefonos =  { "576019181316", "593987654321", "4930609859535", "551146733487", "8004610335" };

    foreach(var telef in telefonos)
    {
        var UTIL = PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
        var Numero = UTIL.Parse("+" + telef, null);
        Console.WriteLine("Entrada: " + telef);
        Console.WriteLine("Código de País: " + Numero.CountryCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Número: " + Numero.NationalNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Codigo de Región : " + UTIL.GetRegionCodeForNumber(Numero));
        Console.WriteLine("===================================");
    }
}
```

Nota: Si te fijas a los número hay que agregar el prefijo "+"

Resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]